# Dropdown not updating in React

Tags: reactjs

The problem is I have two dropdowns; date and document type. When the user changes the date, the document types change to reflect the new date. So Jan 2019 may have doc type a, b, and c. Feb 2019 has doc type e, f, g. The problem is the document type currently in view does not update when the date changes. So if you have Feb 2019 and doc type G currently selected, if you change the date doc type G is still visible. And when you click on the dropdown the new doc types are there. I can see the data changing. The value\text array looks good. Is there a way I can clear out the dropdown component before repopulating it? Or programmatically fire a change event to force a redraw\repopulate? My React experience is less than one month.

```
onFilterChange = filterState => {
  //I am thinking this is where I would add some kind of change event when the date is selected
  let { filter, value, displayValue } = filterState;
  this.setState(
    prevState => {
      return { [filter]: value };
    },
    () => {
      this.getKeygraphReport();
    }
  );
  if (filter === "quick-selector") {
    this.setState({ displayValue });
  }
};
```

Comment: Please put some of your code here or link to a codesandbox.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your code, and clear details of the issue, repro steps, and expected result/behavior

Comment: There are also some custom libraries. So I can't give you a complete picture.

Comment: onFilterChange = filterState => { //I am thinking this is where I would add some kind of change event when the date is selected
    let { filter, value, displayValue } = filterState;

    this.setState(
      prevState => {
        return {
          [filter]: value
        };
      },
      () => {
        this.getKeygraphReport();
      }
    );

    if (filter === "quick-selector") {
      this.setState({ displayValue });
    }
   
  };

Comment: How do I format this as code?

Comment: @MB using this `

Comment: Formatted and added to your question. It isn't very helpful in seeing why dropdown options aren't updating, though.

Comment: I know, but the project using custom company specific components. So I can give you all a working example. So how do I make the code look good?